# How to fix div to another div with scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-position

i have

```
<div id="div1">
  any not fixed text
  but this div has scrollbar

  <div id="div2">
  this div is fixed (without scrollbar)
  </div>

</div>
```

i need to make `div2` fixed to `div1`, but not fixed to main browser scrollbar. something like "stick div2 to div1".

`div1` has scrollbar, that is why i need to fix `div2`.

if i make this:

```
#div1 {
    position: absolute;
}
#div1 #div2 {
    position: fixed;
}
```

it will fix `div1` and browser's window both, but i need only `div1`.

EXAMPLE to test:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#div1 {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#div1 #div2 {
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br><br>
    <div id="div1">
        <div id="div2">fixed text</div>

            <div style="height: 400px;"></div>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 1400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Q1: how to fix `div2` to `div`**

**Q2: in this case how to `float: right` `div2` to the right side of `div1` (on example it is ~ `margin-left: 350px;`)**

thank you.

Comment: Side note: if you have the ID of the inner div, then you should use `#div2{ /* style */}` instead of `#div1 #div2{ /* style */}` in your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't fix div2 to div1, since fixing a div means "to keep the top of the div, measured from the *inner top* of its *nearest positioned container*, constant". And by *inner top* I mean the upper part of the container, which moves up and down as the user scrolls.

The solution ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/roimergarcia/nykw3/)) would be to fix both div1 and div2 to an outer container. This would be your CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#container{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;   
}

#div1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
#div2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 14px;
    top: 0px;
}​
</style>
```

And this your HTML

```
<br><br><br>
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1">
        <div style="height: 800px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">fixed text</div>               
</div> 
<div style="height: 1400px;"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed is always to the browser window. You can't use it in the context of an element with a scroll bar.

This will work on some levels:
http://jsfiddle.net/WP7GB/1/

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">fixed text</div>
    <div style="height: 400px;"></div>
</div>
<div style="height: 1400px;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1 {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#div2 {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:5px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $div2 = $("#div2");

    $("#div1").scroll(function(e){

        $div2.css("top", this.scrollTop);

    });        

});
```